# CLLocationManager suddenly not asking for permission and not showing up in Privacy tab

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

In my app, I created a class that deals with location services. For example, I start location services like this:

```
- (void)startLocationServices{
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == YES && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
else {
    //NSLog(@"Location services is not enabled");
    //[self locationDeniedPolicy];
}}
```

I make my viewcontrollers subclasses of this location class if I ever needed the location of the user. 
The location class itself is a subclass of UIViewController.

This used to work fine. When the user navigates to a view controller that is a subclass of this location class, it would ask for location permission for the first time. Also, the app would be listed in the privacy tab of the Settings app.

I suddenly realized that the app is no longer showing up in the Privacy tab and is not also asking for location permission. It does not use the location services at all! I have no idea why this happened? Was it an update to xcode that changed things? No idea!

Any clue?